Crystal Reports 2013 - Can I summarize a field with multiple variables
I am using Crystal Reports 2013 and want to find an average of a process time based on two variables. My data looks like this:

{Data.TraumaBandNo} - a semi-unique identifier that can be duplicated that identifies individual patients.
{Data.Contacted} - The time we were contacted
{Data.Notified} - The time we notified a receiving facility of a request
{Data.TransferReason} - I use this field to identify records I do not want in my calculated

{@Telemed}
IF {Data.TransferReason} in ["1","2","3"] THEN
      TRUE
      ELSE FALSE`
Then I have another formula intended to identify only the first instance of the {Data.TraumaBandNo} field
`{@TraumaBandNoDup}
  IF {Data.TraumaBandNo} = PREVIOUS({Data.TraumaBandNo}) THEN
  TRUE
  ELSE FALSE`

Then I use another formula to calculate the time based on the {@Telemed} formula
IF {@Telemed} = TRUE AND {@TraumaBandNoDup} = FALSE THEN
   TIME({Data.Notified})-TIME({Data.Contacted}))
   ELSE 0

I can get the calculation for each row but now I want to average it at a group level and a grand total average in the report footer. When I try to summarize the field, I get a warning that it cannot be summarized and the formula
IF {Data.TraumaBandNo} = PREVIOUS({Data.TraumaBandNo}) THEN
  TRUE
  ELSE FALSE

cannot be used because it must be evaluated later.
I suspect that I need to eliminate the second and greater instances of the {Data.TraumaBandNo} field prior to any calculations being performed but I don't know how to do this. I have tried breaking the formulae down in hopes that they could be evaluated at different times during the different passes Crystal does when printing the report but it looks like anything I drop into the details is calculated in a later pass. I have also tried to suppress records using the section expert by suppressing records where {Data.TraumaBandNo}=PREVIOUS({Data.TraumaBandNo}) to no avail.
